# Errors when attempting to run template from College Mathematics Journal

Tags: errors

I am relatively new to LaTeX. I downloaded a [LaTeX template from the magazine College Mathematics Journal](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/CMJ-style-files.zip), and when running it I get a string of messages:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Woodrow_Wilson.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    

l.26 ...=84pt]{Woodrow_Wilson.pdf}}Woodrow Wilson]

?
```

Can anyone help me remove these errors so I can get started?

Comment: The error message just says that it can't find the (image) file `Woodrow_Wilson.pdf` So what shall we do about this?

Comment: It's a graphic file that is included in `CMJ-style-files.zip`.

Comment: To Bernard: Yes, the file is on my hard drive.  How do I get LaTeX to access it?

Comment: Create a directory, like `test`, copy all files (`tex`, `sty` and `pdf` files)  from the `zip` file into directory `test` and  compile the `tex` file.

Answer (score 2):

Extract all files from `CMJ-style-files.zip` into a new directory, 
for example `c:\users\myuser\documents\test` (`c:\users\myuser\documents` is the 
standard path for user `myuser` for windows os).

Check, that all files, especially `.tex`, `.sty` and `.pdf`have been extracted into directory `test`.

Then just compile the file `article-template.tex` or `capsule_template.tex`, which ever you used ...